# Find all positive integers $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{b^2+1}{2a}$, $\sqrt{ 2^{b-1} + a + 4}$ are both integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find all positive integers $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{b^2+1}{2a}$, $\sqrt{ 2^{b-1} + a + 4}$ are both integers

My thoughts: can we prove that $2^{b-1} + a + 4$ must be able to rewrite as $(2^{k}+2)^2$ so $b=2k+1$ and $a = 2^{k+2}$?

Apologies that in an initial version I mixed up $a$ and $b$

Comment: A quick search up to $(204,25)$ turned up $(1,3)$ and $(61,11)$  You cannot decompose the square that way, as $(61,11)$ has the square $1089$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac{b^2 + 1}{2a}$ is an integer, we see that $b$ must be odd.

Also: $\sqrt{2^{b - 1} + a + 4} > \sqrt{2^{b - 1}} = 2^\frac{b - 1}2$.

Since both sides are integers, we must have $\sqrt{2^{b - 1} + a + 4} \geq 2^\frac{b - 1}2 + 1$.

This gives: $$2^{b - 1} + a + 4 \geq (2^\frac{b - 1}2 + 1)^2 = 2^{b - 1} + 2^\frac{b + 1}2 + 1,$$
which is equivalent to: $$a \geq 2^\frac{b + 1}2 - 3.\tag{1}$$

But since $\frac{b^2 + 1}{2a}$ is a positive integer, hence at least $1$, we know that: $$a \leq \frac{b^2 + 1}2.\tag{2}$$

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we get: $$2^\frac{b + 1}2 - 3 \leq \frac{b^2 + 1}2.\tag{3}$$

Now the left hand side of $(3)$ grows exponentially with respect to $b$, while the right hand side grows polynomially. Hence $(3)$ cannot hold for $b$ larger than a certain bound.

---

More precisely, let $f:\Bbb R_{> 0} \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be the function defined by $f(x) = 2^\frac{x + 1}2 - 3 - \frac{x^2 + 1}2$. Taking derivative, we have: $$f'(x) = 2^\frac{x - 1}2\cdot\ln(2) - x.$$ Taking derivative again, we have: $$f''(x) = 2^\frac{x - 3}2\cdot (\ln 2)^2 - 1.$$ Hence for all $x > 7$, we have: $f''(x) > 2^2\ln(2)^2 - 1 > 0$.

So the function $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing on the interval $(7, \infty)$.

But we also have $f'(9) = 2^4 \cdot \ln(2) - 9 > 0$. This shows that the function $f$ is strictly increasing on the interval $(9, \infty)$.

Finally, it is directly verified that $f(11) = 0$, hence $f(x) > 0$ for all real numbers $x > 11$.

---

Thus from our inequality $(3)$, we conclude that $b \leq 11$.

It only remains to check all odd numbers $b \leq 11$, and for each $b$, check all divisors $a$ of $\frac{b^2 + 1}2$, whether the number $\sqrt{2^{b - 1} + a + 4}$ is integer.

The only solutions are $(a, b) = (1, 3),(61, 11)$.

Comment: A non-calculus alternative to your excellent solution: show by induction $2^n\geq n^3$ for $n\geq 10$, then for odd $b\geq 19$, inequality $(3)$ gives us $$\frac{b^2+1}{2}\geq \left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)^3-3 \Leftrightarrow \\ b^2(b-1)+3(b-9)\leq 0$$ which is clearly false, so $b\leq 17$. Three more cases to check, though.